# Why does \crtcref produce this bizarre error?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref, amsart, crossreftools

This question is not about solving a problem *per se*, as I already have a workaround, as deomstrated by point 1 below. It's more about trying to understand why a certain error is occuring. Consider the following very simple example, which contains a couple of `<...>` fields to be replaced so I don't have to type out many similar blocks of code.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{<theorem_environment_name>}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage{crossreftools}

\begin{document}

\begin{<theorem_environment_name>}\label{thm:main}
    text
\end{<theorem_environment_name>}

<ref1>

\section{Proof of <ref2>}

\end{document}
```

1. When `<theorem_environment_name> = theorem` and `<ref1> = <ref2> = \crtcref{thm:main}`, the whole thing builds fine, and produces the references as expected in both places, even in the PDF outline.
2. When `<theorem_environment_name> = thm`, and `<ref1> = <ref2> = \crtcref{thm:main}`, the whole thing breaks. The first build attempt produces no errors, but gives undefined reference warnings, no references are printed anywhere, and no PDF outline is produced. The second build attempt produces a million fatal errors from inside `crossreftools`, and no pages of output. Repeatedly building produces this alternating pattern of warnings and errors.
3. Here's where it gets really odd. When `<theorem_environment_name> = thm`, `<ref1> = \crtcref{thm:main}`, but `<ref2>` is just removed, the whole thing builds fine again, with the one reference where expected, and a PDF outline (which obviously contains no reference).

As an extra test, I tried other types of proclamation as well. `\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}` works fine, as does `{proposition}{Proposition}`, `{lemma}{Lemma}`, and even `{result}{Result}`. But if I try anything like `{prop}{Proposition}`, it breaks as above. Also it doesn't like `{conjecture}{Conjecture}`. It seems as though `\crtcref` has a list of allowed environment names, but I can't find such a list anywhere in the [package documentation](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/crossreftools/crossreftools_doc.pdf) for `crossreftools`.

Can anyone explain why `\crtcref` is so fussy about the name of a theorem environment, ***but only inside a section heading?!***

My build setup: `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)`

Comment: hyperref does basically an \xdef on the section heading to expand it to get the text for the bookmarks. Complicated, non expandable commands either break completly (if they aren't robust) or are removed in this process. Both doesn't give the wanted output. Such commands need a careful written fallback definition to make them usable in bookmarks, something that not many package writers do.

Comment: The docs for crossreftools state that \crtcref is expandable. If it were just that \crtcref were not expandable, then surely point 1 would cause an error?

Comment: @TomSharpe The difference is that with `theorem` you get `\cref@theorem@name` expanding to `theorem`, whereas with `thm` (or any other string) you get `\cref@thm@name` expanding to `\protect\MakeLowercase{T}heorem`, which is obviously the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is quite involved and has to do with how `cleveref` acts in order to assign the right name to references.

With `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}`, the package defines `\cref@theorem@name` to expand to `theorem`. On the other hand, with `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}`, the relevant control sequence is `\cref@thm@name` that expands to `\protect\MakeLowercase{T}heorem` and this is where the thing fails with `crossreftools`.

Probably some further surgery should be done, but in your case the following works: the trick is to substitute `\MakeLowercase` in the relevant parts with `\ExpandableMakeLowercase` that uses `\text_lowercase:n`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{crossreftools}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \ExpandableMakeLowercase \text_lowercase:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@othm}{\MakeLowercase}{\ExpandableMakeLowercase}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@ynthm}{\MakeLowercase}{\ExpandableMakeLowercase}{}{}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}%[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\label{thm:main}
    text
\end{thm}

\crtcref{thm:main}

\section{Proof of \crtcref{thm:main}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't build for me. I get `Undefined control sequence. [\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}]`. Further digging seems to imply it doesn't understand `\ExpandableMakeLowercase`

Comment: @TomSharpe You should update your TeX distribution.